# configuration for setting up nginx with django and nodejs for websocket (wss://)

Tags: node.js, django, nginx, websocket

I have the following configuration to setup django app to be served via uwsgi on nginx

```
upstream node{
    server 127.0.0.1:8081  max_fails=1 fail_timeout=20s;

}
server {
    listen 8000 default_server ssl;
    server_name bla.bla;

    ssl_certificate path;
    ssl_certificate_key path;

    location /serve {
        proxy_pass http://node;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass 1;
        proxy_no_cache 1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_connect_timeout 2s;
    }
    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:///var/uwsgi/sel.sock;
    }
}
```

I have a nodejs server with a websocket server running on port 8081

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  , wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8081, path: "/serve" });
```

Now when I access the websocket server on my html page using

```
var websocket = new WebSocket("wss://host:8081/serve"); // works
var websocket = new WebSocket("wss://host:8000/serve"); // doesn't work get 504 error
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone point out my mistake and show a pointer for configuring it properly.

EDIT: my nginx version is nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Have you tried to increase the `proxy_connect_timeout` value?

Comment: @VBart yes, I put it to 30, still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure if this chat works, but I saw your post with Node+Nginx+Django+Websocket. I'm trying to setup the same exact configuration. Do you have a blog or series of resources you can share to help guide me with configurations and settings?  I think I was able create a chat here (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121421/room-for-thatsrightjack-and-pavan-k) but it might not work. Anyway, just looking for some guidance for the same setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wss` presumes an encrypted WebSocket connection using TLS. If `wss://host:8081` works, then your node.js listens for encrypted connections. But you have configured nginx for TLS termination and proxying unencrypted data.

Comment: How to configure it properly ? Any pointers are appreciated? I tried everything but can't quite seem to figure it out.

Comment: @PavanK First of all, please check if the URI that used with nginx works: `new WebSocket("wss://host:8081/serve");`

Comment: Yes, it works on that path. I edited the post with the new config as well. I posted the older config earlier.

Comment: https did the trick. I can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks a lot for your help. You can edit the answer and I will accept it

Comment: But it would be better if you will find a way how to configure nodejs for unencrypted websockets. I have no experience with nodejs and can't help with it.

Comment: Any reason to listen for unencrypted websockets? All data is encrypted which is good isn't it ?

Comment: It's waste of resources to encrypt and decrypt data just for passing it between processes on the local machine.

Comment: Oh I was under the impression that encrypted data is just forwarded to nodejs from html websocket. I want my websocket data to be on wss at the client side eventually. If I listen for ws:// all the data is visible right?

Comment: Your nginx is listening for encrypted data, then it decrypts the data, that's how it knows the hostname and URI of the request. You don't need to reencrypt it again to pass to node.js.